# Is .net transaction default to read committed? Is this why can't read from table where insert is done until commit?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, transactions, commit

I set up a .net transcation where I inserted into Table1
then Updated Table2, then commited.

Immediately after the insert was done into Table1 (before the commit), I could not read from Table1 - it was locked for reading any record until commit/rollback.

Is this because the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) .net isolation level is "READ COMMITTED"?
Will READ COMMITTED cause this behaviour?

Now because of this I did the transaction in a SQL Stored Proc.
The default behaviour is different here - I can read after the Insert , and before the commit.
What is the default isolation level then for SQL Server 2005? Same/Different than .net? Can anyone comment on this please?

Comment: Does your SP explicitly defines transaction with `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT` ?

Comment: e.g. USE AdventureWorks

BEGIN TRAN

 Insert into Person.Address(AddressLine1,City,StateProvinceID,PostalCode,rowguid,ModifiedDate)
 select '1973 Napa Ct.','Bothell',79,'98011','9AADCB0D-36CF-483F-84D8-585C2D4EC6E3',getdate()

 select * from Person.Address

ROLLBACK